# Swift operator defined in multiple libraries; "ambiguous"

Tags: swift, namespaces, operators

I am have to external libraries I am using in an iOS project

```
pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.10.1'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 1.3'
```

In a class, I am trying to use both:

```
import Foundation
import SQLite
import ObjectMapper

class SqlLiteDataManager
{
   init()
   {
      let insert = experiences.insert(json <- jsonValue, isPublicExpr <- isPublic)
   }
}
```

The "<-" now throws an error since it is defined in both libraries ..
The error thrown is **Ambiguous operator declaration found for operator**

So .. besides creating a separate file, is there a way to solve this with the same class / file?

Comment: Disambiguating things is currently problematic. Do type hints help? That would look like `experiences.insert((json <- jsonValue) as Setter, (isPublicExpr <- isPublic) as Setter)`.

Comment: You could only import the stuff you need from one framework (e.g. `import protocol ObjectMapper.Mappable`), then this frameworks operator isn't available.

Comment: Thank you for the help.. i broke this up to two different classes